# DB2 AS/400 jtopen-7.1 DatabaseMetaData changes

Tags: db2-400, database-metadata, jtopen

I am connecting to DB2 AS 400 V6R1m0 using jt400 7.1 driver. In 7.1 driver IBM have made changes in Database metadata methods. 
One  such change is allowing user to get table-names on the current schema using the ‘*USRLIBL’ keyword . The documentation for the same can be found at : http://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/files/ which says

> By default, the "metadata source" connection property is set to 1, and
>   in that case, information from all schemas is returned if null is
>   passed for the schema pattern.  You can however pass in the special
>   value of *USRLIBL yourself and get the desired results

So fetching table names using the keyword  ‘*USRLIBL’ goes like this.

```
ResultSet rs = mtdt.getTables("S063AAD5",”*USRLIBL”, null, null);
      SYNTAX : getTables(String catalog,
                           String schemaPattern,
                           String tablePattern,
                           String[] tableTypes)
```

This is working fine.

If we use the same pattern to get the procedure names an empty set is returned .

```
ResultSet rs = mtdt.getProcedures("S063AAD5","*USRLIBL", null);
SYNTAX : getProcedures(String catalog,
                           String schemaPattern,
                           String procedurePattern)
```

Can we use the keyword “*USRLIBL” in getProcedures call ? Whether the usage of “*USRLIBL” is supported in getProcedures() call. 
Or should we  continue using null for schema pattern while making use of getProcedures call().